# Setting up _googWcmGet for AdWords Call Tracking Conversions

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

Please Help,

I am trying to setup a tracking code for Google AdWords tracking calls from a website. I have generated the code provided by google and now they are asking me to create the following:

"Generate a code snippet to replace your phone number with a Google forwarding number using the _googWcmGet function. The function has these parameters: _googWcmGet(target, business_number, options)"

I am unsure where to place this or how to get it working. I have tried many options, please help.

I am working from https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1722054?hl=en&ref_topic=3165803

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1722054?hl=en ("Track calls from a website"), in the example below they just call it with the onload-attribute of the body-tag, like this:

```
<body onload="_googWcmGet('number', '1-800-123-4567')">
  <span class="number">1-800-123-4567</span>
</body>
```

This just replaces all spans with class "number" with the tracking-number. The first parameter ("number" in this case) is the class name of your element.

If your element doesn´t have a class, you need to specify a custom callback-function as first parameter.
This example assumes that your element has the id "number", but of course you could use every possibility JavaScript has to identify dom elements:

```
<head> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var callback = function(formatted_number, unformatted_number ) {
      // formatted_number: number to display, in same formatting as number
      //        passed to _googWcmGet(). e.g '1-800-444-5555' in this case
      // unformatted_number: number to display without any formatting. e.g.
      //        '18004445555' 
      var e = document.getElementById("number");
      e.innerHTML = ""
      e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(formatted_number));
    };
 </script>
</head>
<body onload="_googWcmGet(callback, '1-800-123-4567')">
  <span id="number">1-800-123-4567</span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

One useful addition here: there's a hidden debugging tool that the Google dev team provides when `#google-wcc-debug` is added to the URL.

Just add the hash to the URL where you want to test this, hit enter and then refresh the page. You should see a dialog appear at the bottom of the page with a **FORCE** button in the upper right. Clicking this button will force a phone swap with the number 99999999, which is really helpful for testing.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example:

```
<body onload="_googWcmGet('number', '1-800-123-4567')">
  <span class="number">1-800-123-4567</span>
</body>
```

Could the number be formatted as (e.g., dropping the "1-"):

```
<body onload="_googWcmGet('number', '800-123-4567')">
  <span class="number">800-123-4567</span>
</body>
```